# Issues with SecureCRT: SSH to VPSs at AWS and Oracle cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, openssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Just giving it a try here to see if anyone has any suggestions.

- OS is MacOS.
- SecureCRT requested to buy newer version otherwise they will no look into it.
- Using SecureCRT licensed version:

> Version 8.5.4 (build 1942)   -   Official Release - May 30, 2019'

I am having issues with SSH 3x VPS at AWS and Oracle cloud. The errors are the same for all 3x servers.

This works using the terminal:

> ssh -i /Users/user1/Documents/Misc/Oracle/Oracle-Cloud-PiHole.key ubuntu@myserver.com

SecureCRT does not work, using the following session key parameter in the ini file:

> S:"Identity Filename V2"=${VDS_USER_DATA_PATH}/Misc/Oracle/Oracle-Cloud-PiHole.key

Even If trying the public key does not work: Oracle-Cloud-PiHole.key.pub

I tried the recommendation at this link and it still does not work:

https://forums.vandyke.com/showthread.php?t=2185

- Trace Options Output:

  [PRINTER] : Printer initialization succeeded: Core Printing status code: 0
  [LOCAL] : SSH2Core version 8.5.0.1942
  [LOCAL] : Connecting to myserver.com:22 ...
  [LOCAL] : Resolved hostname to IP-for-myserver.com::22
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_NOT_CONNECTED to STATE_EXPECT_KEX_INIT
  [LOCAL] : Using protocol SSH2
  [LOCAL] : RECV : Remote Identifier = 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1'
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote can re-key
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote sends language in password change requests
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote sends algorithm name in PK_OK packets
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote sends algorithm name in public key packets
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote sends algorithm name in signatures
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote sends error text in open failure packets
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote sends name in service accept packets
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote includes port number in x11 open packets
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote uses 160 bit keys for SHA1 MAC
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote supports new diffie-hellman group exchange messages
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote correctly handles unknown SFTP extensions
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote correctly encodes OID for gssapi
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote correctly uses connected addresses in forwarded-tcpip requests
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote can do SFTP version 4
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote uses SHA1 hash in RSA signatures for x.509v3
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote x.509v3 uses ASN.1 encoding for DSA signatures
  [LOCAL] : CAP  : Remote correctly handles zlib@openssh.com
  [LOCAL] : SEND : KEXINIT
  [LOCAL] : RECV : Read kexinit
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Kex Methods = curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
  [LOCAL] : Selected Kex Method = curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Host Key Algos = rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
  [LOCAL] : Selected Host Key Algo = ssh-ed25519
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Send Ciphers = chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  [LOCAL] : Selected Send Cipher = aes256-ctr
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Recv Ciphers = chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  [LOCAL] : Selected Recv Cipher = aes256-ctr
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Send Macs = umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  [LOCAL] : Selected Send Mac = hmac-sha1
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Recv Macs = umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  [LOCAL] : Selected Recv Mac = hmac-sha1
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Compressors = none,zlib@openssh.com
  [LOCAL] : Selected Compressor = none
  [LOCAL] : Available Remote Decompressors = none,zlib@openssh.com
  [LOCAL] : Selected Decompressor = none
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_EXPECT_KEX_INIT to STATE_KEY_EXCHANGE
  [LOCAL] : SEND : SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
  [LOCAL] : RECV : SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_KEY_EXCHANGE to STATE_READY_FOR_NEW_KEYS
  [LOCAL] : RECV: Remote Hostkey (SHA-2 hash hex): 98:c5:47:29:93:af:36:30:5e:1c:d3:b0:e3:ab:87:56:6e:59:28:2b:35:f3:e1:92:c4:0d:58:30:01:00:fc:99
  [LOCAL] : RECV: Remote Hostkey (SHA-2 hash base64): mMVHKZOvNjBeHNOw46uHVm5ZKCs18+GSxA1YMAEA/Jk
  [LOCAL] : RECV: Remote Hostkey (SHA-1 hash): 75:cb:b1:23:15:d1:08:45:1e:e9:12:a9:56:a1:18:e9:ec:33:86:17
  [LOCAL] : RECV: Remote Hostkey (MD5 hash): 0a:0e:1e:88:07:25:33:3d:a3:94:53:7c:94:d5:41:d8
  [LOCAL] : SEND : NEWKEYS
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_READY_FOR_NEW_KEYS to STATE_EXPECT_NEWKEYS
  [LOCAL] : RECV : NEWKEYS
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_EXPECT_NEWKEYS to STATE_CONNECTION
  [LOCAL] : SEND: SERVICE_REQUEST[ssh-userauth]
  SecureCRT - Version 8.5.4 (build 1942)
  [LOCAL] : RECV: SERVICE_ACCEPT[ssh-userauth] -- OK
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [none]
  [LOCAL] : Authenticating as user ubuntu
  [LOCAL] : RECV : USERAUTH_FAILURE, continuations [publickey]
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [publickey (ssh-rsa) - unsigned,fingerprint (SHA-2 hash): 95:31:93:dd:83:49:2e:1c:fa:5d:30:7d:15:9a:59:ae:35:c0:51:b9:e5:de:6f:db:21:58:86:7b:07:dd:3f:1a]
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [publickey (ssh-rsa) - unsigned,fingerprint (SHA-1 hash): d0:05:68:05:b3:c2:b2:ed:9d:f1:63:fb:2c:6a:33:c1:8b:c9:b5:a7]
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [publickey (ssh-rsa) - unsigned,fingerprint (MD5 hash): 31:56:e5:e3:80:38:45:6d:91:dc:0a:81:cc:c9:5f:af]
  [LOCAL] : RECV : USERAUTH_FAILURE, continuations [publickey]
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [publickey (ssh-rsa) - unsigned,agent,fingerprint (SHA-2 hash): b9:d5:4e:9f:5b:ea:6d:53:8c:f7:47:4b:9a:1e:d6:55:41:a4:f5:8a:36:38:7d:ca:0d:12:f0:40:28:60:4a:56]
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [publickey (ssh-rsa) - unsigned,agent,fingerprint (SHA-1 hash): 1f:b6:44:55:17:8e:5b:73:85:8f:b5:96:f3:5b:18:7a:ee:0a:e4:da]
  [LOCAL] : SENT : USERAUTH_REQUEST [publickey (ssh-rsa) - unsigned,agent,fingerprint (MD5 hash): 7c:39:67:ef:7d:88:f7:74:dc:6a:2b:76:14:f8:ed:90]
  [LOCAL] : RECV : USERAUTH_FAILURE, continuations [publickey]
  [LOCAL] : SEND: Disconnect packet: The user canceled authentication.
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_CONNECTION to STATE_SEND_DISCONNECT
  [LOCAL] : Changing state from STATE_SEND_DISCONNECT to STATE_CLOSED
  [LOCAL] : Connected for 2 seconds, 2218 bytes sent, 1537 bytes received

  [LOCAL] : Stream has closed [CLOSE_TYPE_NO_AUTO_RECONNECT] : The user canceled authentication.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me...
https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/989#issuecomment-1117074996

```
Open file "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

Add the line below
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa

Restart the service sshd
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```